# c++ map into min heap

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, stl, heap

I want to know an easy way to obtain a (Map + min-Heap) data structure
in C++

I tried this:

```
struct Comp
{
    bool operator()(const pair<int,int>& y , const pair<int,int>& z)
    {
        return (y.second < z.second);
    }
};

priority_queue< pair<int,int> , map<int,int> , Comp > p;
```

now the problem I face is with re-initialisation since it is in `priority_queue` we can't just simply initialise like we do with `maps`.
The only way to insert element is

```
p.push(make_pair(value1,value2));
```

I have also tried to use simple maps instead of using it with `priority_queue` but the problem again is when I try to find the minimum element using `min_element` it returns the value instead of the key which is also required here.

Please suggest the fastest possible way to execute the problem.
I also believe that there are ways possible beyond my knowledge.

Comment: The second parameter of `priority_queue` "must satisfy the requirements of SequenceContainer, and its iterators must satisfy the requirements of RandomAccessIterator. Additionally, it must provide the following functions with the usual semantics: front() push_back() pop_back()" --http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue
.
`std::map` meets none of these requirements.

Comment: Why do you think you want a map + min-heap? This is an [X,Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Ryuzaki Do you want a way to change the values of an element (`pair <int, int>`) within the priority queue? And you want a way to be able to index that element within the priority queue to change it?

Comment: @MooingDuck , Sir I need it because I was implementing Dijkstra in a very optimised way in c++.

Comment: If you're doing dijkstra then you do want a min-heap (priority_queue).  That cannot be done with a map.  Let it use the default underlying type (vector).

Comment: @ShubhamBhattar, Sir I think the problem now is to find **index** from 'iterator'.Can this thing happen?

Comment: You do not want the index.  You want the minimum, which you obtain from top/pop

Comment: And observe that though it is not a priority queue, a regular (ordered) map enforces the heap invariant and its minimum can be obtained using `std::begin(my_map)`

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve though. A regular priority queue is enough for Dijkstra, how do you want to optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot index elements in a priority queue to change the values. You either have to implement the whole priority queue yourself with the `changeKey()` operation (which can be very optimised by the way), or do some other workaround.

I have implemented a priority queue with `decreaseKey()` operation for Prim's algorithm to calculate Minimum Spanning Trees. If you want to implement the priority queue then you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422633/3160529) or for some other workarounds check Gassa's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422682/3160529).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you review the first comment, and follow the link to the documentation of priority_queue, then you have all the tools you need.

Let's suppose you already have an edge defined somewhere.  Let's say

```
struct edge {
    int vertex1, vertex2;
    int weight;
    bool operator> (const edge &ref) const {return weight > ref.weight;}
};
```

You need a heap, which according to the docs should be based on vector or deque. I usually prefer vector, but I put deque here just for fun. The docs say use std::greater if you want a min-heap, therefore you also must implement edge::operator>

```
#include <queue>      // std::priority_queue and std::deque
#include <functional> // std::greater
typedef std::priority_queue<edge, std::deque<edge>, std::greater<edge> > djikstra_heap;
```

Now you are able to push edges and get the min.

```
edge e1{ 1, 2, 2 };
edge e2{ 1, 3, 4 };

djikstra_heap heap;
heap.push(e1);
heap.push(e2);
edge first_result = heap.top(); heap.pop();
```

Comment: Thank you very much